# How to make CSS transition more smooth using percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a main page and a side menu whose width is 0 at first. The main page's width is 100% and consists of a button. When clicking on the button, the side menu's width will grow up to 50% and the main page's margin-right will grow up to 50%. I've used CSS transition and some JavaScript code but it doesn't work smoothly. What's your suggestion?

I do not want to use 'px' instead of percentage.

Here is the example:

```js
function openRightSide() {
  leftSide.style.marginRight = "50%";
  rightSide.style.width = "50%";
}

function closeLeftSide() {
  leftSide.style.marginRight = "0";
  rightSide.style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.left-side-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  transition: margin 0.9s;
}

.right-side-container {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="left-side-container" id="leftSide">
    <button onclick="openRightSide()">Show Right Side</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side-container" id="rightSide">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeLeftSide()">&times;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: smoothly????Its Working!

Comment: What do you mean by word smoothly ? it's already has smoothly transition

Comment: You could try using a CSS class to represent the expanded state instead of inline styles, but I doubt that would make it any smoother than it already is.

Comment: Do you mean you want it to be less linear (slow down at the end instead of coming to an abrupt stop?) You need to use a [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) on the transition property for that, such as `transition: width 0.9s ease-in-out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin is a heavy operation on a transition better to use `transform: translateX(50%)` to get a smoother transition.

With a margin transition, the dom needs to check all elements position relative to the one you're animating. Transform changes the element independent of the other elements.

This also applies to the width. Use `transform: scale(0)`.

Comment: But this will transform 50% of the right-side's width out of the page!

Comment: You should tween the transform to your liking. `transform: translateX(-50%)` will put it to the left. The important part is that margin transition is slow and that a transform transition can do the trick for fast transitions.